# Pass Laravel Config array to VueJs Component

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a Laravel (5.7) config array, which I want to pass to a VueJS (2.5.7) component to populate a dropdown.

Config Array:

```
'heard_about' => [
    'Inspire Conference',
    'ULearn Conference',
    'NZPF Conference',
    'Interface Magazine',  
    'Facebook',
    'Other'    
]
```

VueJS Component

```
<registration-form :heard-about-options="{{ Config::get('enums.heard_about') }}" />
```

But I get the error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Any ideas on the best way to get this array into Vue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `heard_about` configuration is an array, you cant use `{{ }}`. Double curly bracket in blade file will be transpiled to `echo htmlspecialchars($anything)`. To pass an array configuration to Vue component, use `@json` directive instead:

```
<registration-form
  :heard-about-options="@json(Config::get('enums.heard_about'))" />
```